# Matlab: Test if expression is valid without disturbing main process

Tags: matlab

I am generating expressions with a GP'ish (genetic programming) process and I want to test if an offspring candidate has a valid Matlab syntax directly after it is generated. This implies that in the case it is invalid the main process can not be disturbed which results in a kind of solution with a child process. Is there a direct way to do this instead of writing a m-file with eval(expression) in it, calling it from inside Matlab, writing the response in a variable and analyzing it with isnumeric (if such a pipeline even works).

Answer (score 0):

I have the following part-solutions but both proposed system-strings have their faults:

```
% WRITE m-file WITH EXPRESSION AS STRING IN P_prim 
P_prim_name = 'test_verification.m';
fileID = fopen(P_prim_name, 'wt');
formatSpec = '%s';
L1 = 'F = ';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,L1);
formatSpec = '''%s''';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,P_prim);                            
L2 = ';';
formatSpec = '%s\n';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,L2);
L3 = 'z = 2; Matlab_return = eval(F);'; 
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,L3);       
fclose(fileID);

% MAKE SYSTEM-STRING AND CALL 
Matlab_systemstring = strcat('matlab -nodesktop -r "run(''', P_prim_name, '''); save(''test_verification_result'', ''Matlab_return''); exit"');
% halt before getting to exit if expression is invalid
Matlab_systemstring = strcat('matlab -nodesktop -r "try, run(''', P_prim_name, '''); save(''test_verification_result'', ''Matlab_return''); catch, exit, end, exit"');
% generates some numeric values even if expression is invalid
system(Matlab_systemstring);

% LOAD mat-file AND ANALYSE VARIABLE 
clear Matlab_return
load('test_verification_result.mat'); disp(['Matlab_return = ', num2str(Matlab_return)]);
if isnumeric(Matlab_return) == 1; 
    disp('Matlab_return IS numeric => expression valid'); 
else; 
    disp('Matlab_return IS NOT numeric => expression invalid'); 
end
```